# JQuery multiple option selection with class disable the selected option and enable it again if not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i just wanted to make this thing right, first i have these line of codes in my html file:

```
    <select class="form-control select-option></select>
```

and i got 5 of em like these and then  i appended my datas which come out:

```
    <select class="form-control select-option>
      <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>E</option>
    </select>
```

All I wanted is that if my first select gets option C in the other selects it will be disabled and if i deselect it and rather choose A then let A be disabled and let C be seen in other selects again. How Am I going to that? Need help. Thank you :)

Note: Continously until all select selected a letter :)

Comment: @yezzz you **can not** hide option tag cross browser. Not supported particularly in IE and Safari

Comment: That is mentioned on that page, but I agree this is not a duplicate of link I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".select-option").on("change",function(){
  $(this).find("option").prop("disabled",false).removeClass("disabled");
 $(this).find("option:selected").prop("disabled",true).addClass("disabled");
});
```

```css
.disabled{background-color:#eee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select-option" >
   <option disabled selected >Select an option</option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>E</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that is awesome sir but the fact is i have 5 selects could you make something for even just 2 selects? thank you so much :)